# Matlab/CUDA: ocean wave simulation

Tags: matlab, cuda, simulation, simulator, simulate

I've studied ["Simulating Ocean Water"](http://graphics.ucsd.edu/courses/rendering/2005/jdewall/tessendorf.pdf) article by Jerry Tessendorf and tried to program the Statistical Wave Model but I didn't get correct result and I don't understand why.

In my program I tried only to create a wave height field at time `t = 0` without any further changes in time. After execution of my program I got not what I was expecting:[image]

Here's my source code:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
rng(11); % setting seed for random numbers

meshSize = 64; % field size
windDir = [1, 0]; % ||windDir|| = 1
patchSize = 64;
A = 1e+4;
g = 9.81; % gravitational constant
windSpeed = 1e+2;

x1 = linspace(-10, 10, meshSize+1); x = x1(1:meshSize);
y1 = linspace(-10, 10, meshSize+1); y = y1(1:meshSize);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

H0 = zeros(size(X)); % height field at time t = 0

for i = 1:meshSize
    for j = 1:meshSize
        kx = 2.0 * pi / patchSize * (-meshSize / 2.0 + x(i)); % = 2*pi*n / Lx
        ky = 2.0 * pi / patchSize * (-meshSize / 2.0 + y(j)); % = 2*pi*m / Ly
        P = phillips(kx, ky, windDir, windSpeed, A, g); % phillips spectrum
        H0(i,j) = 1/sqrt(2) * (randn(1) + 1i * randn(1)) * sqrt(P);
    end
end

H0 = H0 + conj(H0);

surf(X,Y,abs(ifft(H0)));
axis([-10 10 -10 10 -10 10]);
```

And the `phillips` function:

```
function P = phillips(kx, ky, windDir, windSpeed, A, g)
    k_sq = kx^2 + ky^2;
    L = windSpeed^2 / g;
    k = [kx, ky] / sqrt(k_sq);
    wk = k(1) * windDir(1) + k(2) * windDir(2);
    P = A / k_sq^2 * exp(-1.0 / (k_sq * L^2)) * wk^2;
end
```

Is there any matlab ocean simulation source code which could help me to understand my mistakes? Fast google search didn't get any results.

---

Here's a "correct" result I got from "CUDA FFT Ocean Simulation". I didn't achieve this behavior in Matlab yet but I've ploted "surf" in matlab using data from  "CUDA FFT Ocean Simulation". Here's what it looks like:
[image]
[image]

---

I've made an experiment and got an interesting result:

I've taken generated `h0` from "CUDA FFT Ocean Simulation". So I have to do ifft to transform from frequency domain to spatial domain to plot the graph. I've done it for the same `h0` using matlab `ifft` and using `cufftExecC2C` from CUDA library. Here's the result:

CUDA ifft:
[image]

Matlab ifft:
[image]

Either I don't understand some aspects of realization of `cufftExecC2C` or `cufftExecC2C` and matlab ifft are different algorithms with different results.

---

By the way parameters for generating such surface are:

- meshSize = 32
- A = 1e-7
- patchSize = 80
- windSpeed = 10

Comment: Can you explain what makes a "correct" result for you?

Comment: I thought it would look like a real ocean surface. Something like [this](http://postimg.org/image/n9gvp7k0f/) but without textures ofcourse.

Comment: Maybe you need to rework your scale? Looks to me like waves with a little bit of "stretching" onto a larger plane.

Comment: In line with runDOSrun's comment, maybe it's insufficient sampling. Try increasing `meshSize`

Comment: You mean in Y-direction? (if XZ is a horizontal plane)

Comment: Increasing `meshSize` doesn't effect anything. (Get the same result)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well that was definitely a funny exercise. This is a completely rewritten answer since you found the issues you were asking about by yourself.

Instead of deleting my answer, there is still merit in posting to help you vectorize and/or explain a few bits of code.

I completely rewrote the GUI I gave in my former answer in order to incorporate your changes and add a couple of options. It started to grew arms and legs so I won't put the listing here but you can find the full file there:

[`ocean_simulator.m`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qow7cdf5z95t7hx/ocean_simulator.m?dl=0).

This is completely self contained and it includes all the calculating functions I vectorized and list separately below.

---

The GUI will allow you to play with the parameters, animate the waves, export GIF file (and a few other options like the "preset", but they are not too ironed out yet). A few examples of what you can achieve:

---

### Basic

This is what you get with the quick default settings, and a couple of rendering options. This uses a small grid size and a fast time step, so it runs pretty quickly on any machine.

[image: water1]

---

I am quite limited at home (Pentium E2200 32bit), so I could only practice with limited settings. The gui will run even with the settings maxed but it will become to slow to really enjoy.

However, with a quick run of [`ocean_simulator`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qow7cdf5z95t7hx/ocean_simulator.m?dl=0) at work (*I7 64 bit, 8 cores, 16GB ram, 2xSSD in Raid*), it makes it much more fun! Here are a few examples:

<sub>Although done on a much better machine, I didn't use any parallel functionality nor any GPU calculations, so Matlab was only using a portion of these specs, which means it could probably run just as good on any 64bit system with decent RAM</sub>

---

### Windy lake

This is a rather flat water surface like a lake. Even high winds do not produce high amplitude waves (but still a lot of mini wavelets). If you're a wind surfer looking at that from your window on top of the hill, your heart is going to skip a beat and your next move is to call Dave "***Man! gear up.*** *Meet you in five on the water!*"
[image: water2]

---

### Swell

This is you looking from the bridge of your boat on the morning, after having battled with the storm all night. The storm has dissipated and the long large waves are the last witness of what was definitely a shaky night (*people with sailing experience will know ...*).
[image: Swell]

---

### T-Storm

And this was what you were up to the night before...
[image: T-Storm]
[image: T-Storm3]
*<sub>second gif done at home, hence the lack of detail ... sorry</sub>*

---

### To the bottom:

Finally, the gui will let you add a patch around the water domain. In the gui it is transparent so you could add objects underwater or a nice ocean bottom. Unfortunately, the GIF format cannot include an alpha channel so no transparency here (but if you export in a video then you should be ok).

Moreover, the export to GIF degrade the image, the joint between the domain border and the water surface is flawless if you run that in Matlab. In some case it also make Matlab degrade the rendering of the lighting, so this is definitely not the best option for export, but it allows more things to play within matlab.
[image: bottom]

---

### Now onto the code:

Instead of listing the full GUI, which would be super long (this post is long enough already), I will just list here the re-written version of *your* code, and explain the changes.

You should notice a massive increase of speed execution (orders of magnitude), thanks to the remaining vectorization, but mostly for two reasons:
(i) A lot of calculations were repeated. Caching values and reusing them is much faster than recalculating full matrices in loops (during the animation part).
(ii) Note how I defined the surface graphic object. It is defined only once (empty even), then all the further calls (in the loop) only update the underlying `ZData` of the surface object (instead of re-creating a surface object at each iteration.

Here goes:

```
%% // clear workspace
clear all; close all; clc;

%% // Default parameters
param.meshsize  = 128 ;     %// main grid size
param.patchsize = 200 ;     
param.windSpeed = 100  ;    %// what unit ? [m/s] ??
param.winddir   = 90   ;    %// Azimuth
param.rng = 13 ;            %// setting seed for random numbers
param.A         = 1e-7 ;    %// Scaling factor
param.g         = 9.81 ;    %// gravitational constant

param.xLim = [-10 10] ;     %// domain limits X
param.yLim = [-10 10] ;     %// domain limits Y
param.zLim = [-1e-4 1e-4]*2 ;

gridSize = param.meshsize * [1 1] ;

%% // Define the grid X-Y domain
x = linspace( param.xLim(1) , param.xLim(2) , param.meshsize ) ;
y = linspace( param.yLim(1) , param.yLim(2) , param.meshsize ) ;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

%% // get the grid parameters which remain constants (not time dependent)
[H0, W, Grid_Sign] =  initialize_wave( param ) ;

%% // calculate wave at t0
t0 = 0 ;
Z = calc_wave( H0 , W , t0 , Grid_Sign ) ;

%% // populate the display panel
h.fig  = figure('Color','w') ;
h.ax   = handle(axes) ;                 %// create an empty axes that fills the figure
h.surf = handle( surf( NaN(2) ) ) ;     %// create an empty "surface" object

%% // Display the initial wave surface
set( h.surf , 'XData',X , 'YData',Y , 'ZData',Z )
set( h.ax   , 'XLim',param.xLim , 'YLim',param.yLim , 'ZLim',param.zLim )

%% // Change some rendering options
axis off                                %// make the axis grid and border invisible
shading interp                          %// improve shading (remove "faceted" effect)
blue = linspace(0.4, 1.0, 25).' ; cmap = [blue*0, blue*0, blue]; %'// create blue colormap
colormap(cmap)
%// configure lighting
h.light_handle = lightangle(-45,30) ;   %// add a light source
set(h.surf,'FaceLighting','phong','AmbientStrength',.3,'DiffuseStrength',.8,'SpecularStrength',.9,'SpecularExponent',25,'BackFaceLighting','unlit')

%% // Animate
view(75,55) %// no need to reset the view inside the loop ;)

timeStep = 1./25 ;
nSteps = 2000 ;
for time = (1:nSteps)*timeStep    
    %// update wave surface
    Z = calc_wave( H0,W,time,Grid_Sign ) ;
    h.surf.ZData = Z ;
    pause(0.001);
end


%% // This block of code is only if you want to generate a GIF file
%// be carefull on how many frames you put there, the size of the GIF can
%// quickly grow out of proportion ;)

nFrame = 55 ;
gifFileName = 'MyDancingWaves.gif' ;

view(-70,40)
clear im
f = getframe;
[im,map] = rgb2ind(f.cdata,256,'nodither');
im(1,1,1,20) = 0;
iframe = 0 ;
for time = (1:nFrame)*.5
    %// update wave surface
    Z = calc_wave( H0,W,time,Grid_Sign ) ;
    h.surf.ZData = Z ;
    pause(0.001);

    f = getframe;
    iframe= iframe+1 ;
    im(:,:,1,iframe) = rgb2ind(f.cdata,map,'nodither');
end
imwrite(im,map,gifFileName,'DelayTime',0,'LoopCount',inf)
disp([num2str(nFrame) ' frames written in file: ' gifFileName])
```

You'll notice that I changed a few things, but I can assure you the calculations are exactly the same. This code calls a few subfunctions but they are all vectorized so if you want you can just copy/paste them here and run everything inline.

---

The first function called is `initialize_wave.m`
*Everything calculated here will be constant later (it does not vary with time when you later animate the waves), so it made sense to put that into a block on it's own.*

```
function [H0, W, Grid_Sign] =  initialize_wave( param )
% function [H0, W, Grid_Sign] =  initialize_wave( param )
%
% This function return the wave height coefficients H0 and W for the
% parameters given in input. These coefficients are constants for a given
% set of input parameters.
% Third output parameter is optional (easy to recalculate anyway)

rng(param.rng);  %// setting seed for random numbers

gridSize = param.meshsize * [1 1] ;

meshLim = pi * param.meshsize / param.patchsize ;
N = linspace(-meshLim , meshLim , param.meshsize ) ;
M = linspace(-meshLim , meshLim , param.meshsize ) ;
[Kx,Ky] = meshgrid(N,M) ;

K = sqrt(Kx.^2 + Ky.^2);    %// ||K||
W = sqrt(K .* param.g);     %// deep water frequencies (empirical parameter)

[windx , windy] = pol2cart( deg2rad(param.winddir) , 1) ;

P = phillips(Kx, Ky, [windx , windy], param.windSpeed, param.A, param.g) ;
H0 = 1/sqrt(2) .* (randn(gridSize) + 1i .* randn(gridSize)) .* sqrt(P); % height field at time t = 0

if nargout == 3
    Grid_Sign = signGrid( param.meshsize ) ;
end
```

Note that the initial `winDir` parameter is now expressed with a single scalar value representing the "azimuth" (*in degrees*) of the wind (anything from 0 to 360). It is later translated to its `X` and `Y` components thanks to the function `pol2cart`.

```
[windx , windy] = pol2cart( deg2rad(param.winddir) , 1) ;
```

This insure that the norm is always `1`.

The function calls your problematic `phillips.m` separately, but as said before it works even fully vectorized so you can copy it back inline if you like. (*don't worry I checked the results against your versions => strictly identical*). Note that this function does not output complex numbers so there was no need to compare the imaginary parts.

```
function P = phillips(Kx, Ky, windDir, windSpeed, A, g)
%// The function now accept scalar, vector or full 2D grid matrix as input
    K_sq = Kx.^2 + Ky.^2;
    L = windSpeed.^2 ./ g;
    k_norm = sqrt(K_sq) ;
    WK = Kx./k_norm * windDir(1) + Ky./k_norm * windDir(2);
    P = A ./ K_sq.^2 .* exp(-1.0 ./ (K_sq * L^2)) .* WK.^2 ;
    P( K_sq==0 | WK<0 ) = 0 ;
end
```

---

The next function called by the main program is `calc_wave.m`. This function finishes the calculations of the wave field *for a given time*. It is definitely worth having that on its own because this is the mimimun set of calculations which will have to be repeated for each given time when you want to animate the waves.

```
function Z = calc_wave( H0,W,time,Grid_Sign )
% Z = calc_wave( H0,W,time,Grid_Sign )
%
% This function calculate the wave height based on the wave coefficients H0
% and W, for a given "time". Default time=0 if not supplied.
% Fourth output parameter is optional (easy to recalculate anyway)

    % recalculate the grid sign if not supplied in input
    if nargin < 4
        Grid_Sign = signGrid( param.meshsize ) ;
    end
    % Assign time=0 if not specified in input
    if nargin < 3 ; time = 0 ; end

    wt = exp(1i .* W .* time ) ;
    Ht = H0 .* wt + conj(rot90(H0,2)) .* conj(wt) ;  
    Z = real( ifft2(Ht) .* Grid_Sign ) ;
end
```

---

The last 3 lines of calculations require a bit of explanation as they received the biggest changes (all for the same result but a much better speed).

Your original line:

```
Ht = H0 .* exp(1i .* W .* (t * timeStep)) + conj(flip(flip(H0,1),2)) .* exp(-1i .* W .* (t * timeStep));
```

recalculate the same thing too many times to be efficient:

`(t * timeStep)` is calculated twice on the line, at each loop, while it is easy to get the proper `time` value for each line when `time` is initialised at the beginning of the loop `for time = (1:nSteps)*timeStep`.
Also note that `exp(-1i .* W .* time)` is the same than `conj(exp(1i .* W .* time))`. Instead of doing 2*m*n multiplications to calculate them each, it is faster to calculate one once, then use the `conj()` operation which is much faster.
So your single line would become:

```
wt = exp(1i .* W .* time ) ;
Ht = H0 .* wt + conj(flip(flip(H0,1),2)) .* conj(wt) ;
```

Last minor touch, `flip(flip(H0,1),2))` can be replaced by `rot90(H0,2)` (also marginally faster).

Note that because the function `calc_wave` is going to be repeated extensively, it is definitely worth reducing the number of calculations (as we did above), but also by sending it the `Grid_Sign` parameter (instead of letting the function recalculate it every iteration). This is why:

Your mysterious function `signCor(ifft2(Ht),meshSize))`, simply reverse the sign of every other element of `Ht`. There is a faster way of achieving that: simply multiply `Ht` by a matrix the same size (`Grid_Sign`) which is a matrix of alternated `+1 -1 ...` and so on.

so `signCor(ifft2(Ht),meshSize)` becomes `ifft2(Ht) .* Grid_Sign`.

Since `Grid_Sign` is only dependent on the matrix size, it does not change for each `time` in the loop, you only calculate it once (before the loop) then use it as it is for every other iteration. It is calculated as follow (*vectorized, so you can also put it inline in your code*):

```
function sgn = signGrid(n)
% return a matrix the size of n with alternate sign for every indice
% ex:     sgn = signGrid(3) ;
%         sgn =
%             -1     1    -1
%              1    -1     1
%             -1     1    -1

    [x,y] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n) ;
    sgn = ones( n ) ;
    sgn(mod(x+y,2)==0) = -1 ;
end
```

---

Lastly, you will notice a difference in how the grids `[Kx,Ky]` are defined between your version and this one. They do produce slightly different result, it's just a matter of choice.
To explain with a simple example, let's consider a small `meshsize=5`. Your way of doing things will split that into 5 values, equally spaced, like so:

```
Kx(first line)=[-1.5 -0.5 0.5 1.5 2.5] * 2 * pi / patchSize
```

while my way of producing the grid will produce equally spaced values, but also centered on the domain limits, like so:

```
Kx(first line)=[-2.50 -1.25 0.0 1.25 2.50] * 2 * pi / patchSize
```

It seems to respect more your comment `% = 2*pi*n / Lx, -N/2 <= n < N/2` on the line where you define it.

I tend to prefer symmetric solutions (plus it is also slightly faster but it is only calculated once so it is not a big deal), so I used my vectorized way, but it is purely a matter of choice, you can definitely keep your way, it only ever so slightly "offset" the whole result matrix, but it doesn't perturbate the calculations per se.

---

*<sub>last remains of the first answer</sub>*
Side programming notes:
I detect you come from the C/C++ world or family. In Matlab you do not need to define decimal number with a coma (like `2.0`, you used that for most of your numbers). Unless specifically defined otherwise, Matlab by default cast any number to `double`, which is a 64 bit floating point type. So writing `2  * pi` is enough to get the maximum precision (*Matlab won't cast pi as an integer ;-)*), you do not need to write `2.0 * pi`. *Although it will still work if you don't want to change your habits.*

Also, (one of the great benefit of Matlab), adding `.` before an operator usually mean "element-wise" operation. You can add (`.+`), substract (`.-`), multiply (`.*`), divide (`./`) full matrix element wise this way. This is how I got rid of all the loops in your code. This also work for the power operator: `A.^2` will return a matrix the same size as `A` with every element squared.

Comment: Thank you very mush for your answer! I really appreciate the huge job you've done. But maybe you may explain one more question: while executing your code I've noticed that waves which can be created are very small but in the article they have pretty big size. If you are interested somehow in this question and know CUDA programming  language, there is a realization of this algorithm in "CUDA FFT Ocean Simulation".

Comment: @EugeneKolesnikov, yes I noticed that the average wavelength of the matlab code was significantly smaller than in the paper example. I was initially thinking to add a couple of longer wavelength components on top of it just to simulate some sort of larger "swell", but i see in your edit that in fact this is caused by a difference in the iFFT results. I am not so well versed in the CUDA coding (and my current AMD graphic card doesn't support it anyway), but I am sure there is a way to make them match.

Comment: @EugeneKolesnikov, Could you share online somewhere an example of the matrix data `H0` you use before the iFFT, and the result from the `cufftExecC2C` transform ? (I can try to make Matlab get the same result).

Comment: I've solved all problems... I'll write detailed explanation in several hours.

Comment: @EugeneKolesnikov. Thanks for your explanations. Sorry it took so long to come back to you. I made it up with some good explanations on my side too ;-)

Comment: @Hoki WTF, this is amazing!

Comment: Hey @AnderBiguri. Yes I got a bit carried away with that one ... but it was really fun for me. Did you try the code ? (_to simulate your garden pond_)

Comment: FYI: `.+` and `.-` are Octave extensions, and do not work in MATLAB. Other than that... wow, that's a lot of effort for an answer. Very impressive results too. Awesome!

Comment: @Hoki. Excellent post. This has helped clear things up immensely. But I'm having trouble understanding a few things. (1) Why do you multiply `ifft2(Ht)` by `Grid_Sign`. I don't see anything like this in the definition of the Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform. (2) Why do we take the real part of the result of `ifft2(Ht) .* Grid_Sign`? Shouldn't this be real naturally? (3) Why do you include this line computing the Phillips Spectrum: `P( K_sq==0 | WK<0 ) = 0 ;`?  Thanks!

Comment: @eball Thanks for the nice comment. I don't pretend to understand the meaning of all the calculations. At the time I mostly took the code of the original post (and only a little bit of help from the linked paper) and rewrote it in a more efficient way. I didn't modify the initial logic at all, I merely optimised the calculations (making sure the results between original code and my version where the same). You might have more luck asking the original poster, or for full details check the [paper itself](https://people.computing.clemson.edu/~jtessen/reports/papers_files/coursenotes2004.pdf).

Comment: @Hoki, thanks for the reply! Yeah I couldn't find where that logic was in the paper you just linked by Tessendorf. Did you get the logic I'm asking about from Eugene Kolesnikov's answer (I don't see it his original question)? Thanks!

Comment: @eball Actually Eugene Kolesnikov gave a hint in his **answer** below: "_`signCor.m`: (This function is an absolutely mystery for me... I've copied it from "CUDA FFT Ocean Simulation" realization. Simulation works much worse without it._". In my answer I explain I found out what it was doing and just made a better computation for it (and renamed it `Grid_Sign()`) but I did not introduce it, it was already in the original code.

Comment: @Hoki, yeah I saw that but I havn't been able to find the paper "CUDA FFT Ocean Simulation" to find an explanation for it. I'll keep looking. Thanks again for the great post! Much easier for me to understand MATLAB code than shader code :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cooy1J05c2g)'s the working program.

First of all - source code:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
rng(13); % setting seed for random numbers

meshSize = 128; % field size
windDir = [0.1,1];
patchSize = 200;
A = 1e-7;
g = 9.81; % gravitational constant
windSpeed = 100;
timeStep = 1/25;

x1 = linspace(-10, 10, meshSize+1); x = x1(1:meshSize);
y1 = linspace(-10, 10, meshSize+1); y = y1(1:meshSize);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y); % wave field

i = 1:meshSize; j = 1:meshSize; % indecies
[I,J] = meshgrid(i,j); % field of indecies
Kx = 2.0 * pi / patchSize * (-meshSize / 2.0 + I); % = 2*pi*n / Lx, -N/2 <= n < N/2
Ky = 2.0 * pi / patchSize * (-meshSize / 2.0 + J); % = 2*pi*m / Ly, -M/2 <= m < M/2
K = sqrt(Kx.^2 + Ky.^2); % ||K||
W = sqrt(K .* g); % deep water frequencies (empirical parameter)

P = zeros(size(X)); % Cant compute P without loops
for i = 1:meshSize
    for j = 1:meshSize
        P(i,j) = phillips(Kx(i,j), Ky(i,j), windDir, windSpeed, A, g); % phillips spectrum
    end
end

H0 = 1/sqrt(2) .* (randn(size(X)) + 1i .* randn(size(X))) .* sqrt(P); % height field at time t = 0

rotate3d on;
for t = 1:10000 % 10000 * timeStep (sec)
    Ht = H0 .* exp(1i .* W .* (t * timeStep)) + ...
         conj(flip(flip(H0,1),2)) .* exp(-1i .* W .* (t * timeStep));
    [az,el] = view;
    surf(X,Y,real(signCor(ifft2(Ht),meshSize)));
    axis([-10 10 -10 10 -1e-4 1e-4]); view(az,el);
    blue = linspace(0.4, 1.0, 25)'; map = [blue*0, blue*0, blue];
    %shading interp; % improve shading (remove "faceted" effect)
    colormap(map);
    pause(1/60);
end
```

phillips.m: (I've tried to vectorize the computation of Phillips spectrum but I faced with a difficulty which I'll show further)

```
function P = phillips(kx, ky, windDir, windSpeed, A, g)
    k_sq = kx^2 + ky^2;
    if k_sq == 0
        P = 0;
    else
        L = windSpeed^2 / g;
        k = [kx, ky] / sqrt(k_sq);
        wk = k(1) * windDir(1) + k(2) * windDir(2);
        P = A / k_sq^2 * exp(-1.0 / (k_sq * L^2)) * wk^2;
        if wk < 0
            P = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

signCor.m: (This function is an absolutely mystery for me... I've copied it from "CUDA FFT Ocean Simulation" realization. Simulation works much worse without it. And again I don't know how to vectorize this function.)

```
function H = signCor(H1, meshSize)
    H = H1;
    for i = 1:meshSize
        for j = 1:meshSize
            if mod(i+j,2) == 0
                sign = -1; % works fine if we change signs vice versa
            else
                sign = 1;
            end
            H(i,j) = H1(i,j) * sign;
        end
    end
end
```

---

The biggest mistake that I've done is that I used `ifft` instead of using `ifft2`, that's why CUDA ifft and Matlab ifft didn't match.

My second mistake was in this lines of code:

```
kx = 2.0 * pi / patchSize * (-meshSize / 2.0 + x(i)); % = 2*pi*n / Lx
ky = 2.0 * pi / patchSize * (-meshSize / 2.0 + y(j)); % = 2*pi*m / Ly
```

I should've write:

```
kx = 2.0 * pi / patchSize * (-meshSize / 2.0 + i); % = 2*pi*n / Lx
ky = 2.0 * pi / patchSize * (-meshSize / 2.0 + j); % = 2*pi*m / Ly
```

---

I've played a bit with parameters A, meshSize, patchSize and I came to the conclusion that:

Somehow plausible parameter of wave amplitude is A * (patchSize / meshSize), where A is nothing but a scaling factor.

- For 'calm' `patchSize / meshSize <= 0.5`.
- For 'tsunami' `patchSize / meshSize >= 3.0`.

---

Difficulty with a vectorization of Phillips spectrum:

I have 2 functions:

```
% non-vectorized spectrum
function P = phillips1(kx, ky, windDir, windSpeed, A, g)
    k_sq = kx^2 + ky^2;
    if k_sq == 0
        P = 0;
    else
        L = windSpeed^2 / g;
        k = [kx, ky] / sqrt(k_sq);
        wk = k(1) * windDir(1) + k(2) * windDir(2);
        P = A / k_sq^2 * exp(-1.0 / (k_sq * L^2)) * wk^2;
        if wk < 0
            P = 0;
        end
    end
end

% vectorized spectrum
function P = phillips2(Kx, Ky, windDir, windSpeed, A, g)
    K_sq = Kx .^ 2 + Ky .^ 2;
    L = -g^2 / windSpeed^4;
    WK = (Kx ./ K_sq) .* windDir(1) + (Ky ./ K_sq) .* windDir(2);
    P = (A ./ (K_sq .^ 2)) .* ( exp(L ./ K_sq) .* (WK .^ 2) );
    P(K_sq == 0) = 0;
    P(WK < 0) = 0;
    P(isinf(P)) = 0;
end
```

After I compute `P1` using `phillips1` and `P2` using `phillips2` I plot their difference:

```
subplot(2,1,1); surf(X,Y,real(P2-P1)); title('Difference in real part');
subplot(2,1,2); surf(X,Y,imag(P2-P1)); title('Difference in imaginary part');
```

[image]

It perfectly illustrates that there's a huge difference between this 2 spectrums in real part.

Comment: Good job on sorting out your calculations. There are still a lot of speed improvement you can get. Check out my revised answer. (_Note: your `P` is not `complex` so there is no point in checking the imaginary part_)