# Dynamic Texture Synthesis(ocean wave model)

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab and I am right now working on dynamic texture synthesis. I am trying to create a simple ocean wave model just by changing the pixel values and applying different values of rgb color values to get the proper color intensity. Creating a frame and storing it in a video. But I have a difficulty with it: not actually looking like an ocean wave.

i referred to [Matlab/CUDA: ocean wave simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279337/matlab-cuda-ocean-wave-simulation), but I am not getting how to store each frame in a video.

Here is my Code:

```
x = 1; % horizontal distance
lambda = 150;  % wavelength
c = 5;        % wave speed
A = 9;      % wave amplitude
images= ones(500,500,3);
imshow(images)
start=0;
k=0;

writerobj=VideoWriter('new4.avi');
writerobj.FrameRate=6;
open(writerobj);
rint=200;
gint=200;
bint=200;
height=400;
intinc=1;

images(100:500,:,3)=150;
b=0;



for i=0:1:60
 for height =100:1:500;
 for t= 0:1:499
    y=7*sin((2*3.14/lambda)*x-b);


       y = round(y);
       y=y+height;

       images(y,x+1,1)=rint;
       images(y,x+1,2)=gint;
       images(y,x+1,3)=bint;

      temp=x;
      intex=x;




     x=x+1;
end

if(rint<2250&&bint<225) 
     rint=rint+intinc;
     gint=gint+intinc;
     bint=bint+intinc;
     else
      rint=225;
      gint=225;
      bint=200;
      b=b+10;

 end
  x=1;
  start=0;


end

images=uint8(images);

 writeVideo(writerobj,images);
 images= ones(500,500,3);
 images(100:500,:,3)=150;
 rint=125;
 gint=125; 
 bint=125;


end
close(writerobj);
imshow(images);
```

Comment: What is wrong? I get a video with wavy stuff. What do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: I want it to have a color which will give me a feel of original wave (at least somewhat close to it)